# Finding max gradient of irregular data series from csv

Tags: python, csv, numpy, gradient

Python noob here, but I am attempting to find the max gradient of a dataset (reading from a csv file, with two columns: force and displacement, irregular intervals). I think I have done it correctly based on a simpler example I tested, but I want to check that I should be using diff or whether is there a better, more efficient function to use?

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import numpy as np


df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Data\Specimen_RawData_1.csv', header=10) 
blah = df[(df.Displacement >= 0.05) & (df.Displacement <=0.6)] #crop dataset 

y = blah['Force'] 
dy = np.diff(y)
max_dy = max(dy)

x = blah['Displacement']
dx = np.diff(x)
max_dx = max(dx)

grad = 1. * max_dy/max_dx
print grad
```

Answer (score 0):

For calculating gradients you can always use [`np.gradient`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html#numpy.gradient) instead of `np.diff`. That takes care of your boundary values as well.

Comment: Thanks! So: grad = np.gradient (x,y) ? If I do that then I get an array and the max of that array returns a weird value that is incorrect?

Comment: np.gradient only takes one n-dimensional array of which it calculates the gradients. your second argument (in this case y) will specify the spacing between your values according to the documentation. Working with the relevant axis, you can put x and y into one array and have np.gradient (or even np.diff) calculate all values at once. You will still have to get the maximum gradient by using (np.)max on the specific axis.